# .NET How to access the DBContext within OIDC Middleware

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have the following `Startup.cs` `#ConfigureServices` method:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });

        //Register TracingContext to access the DB
        services.AddDbContext<TracingContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                {
                    // Get the user's email 
                    var email = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

                    // Query the database to get the role
                    **// BUT: How do I access the TracingContext from above?** 
                    **// CODE HERE **

                    // Add claims
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "HQUser")
                    };
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                    ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            };
        });
    }
```

Since I have defined the `TracingContext (DBContext)` in the method by using `services.AddDbContext(...)`, how can I access the TracingContext in the OICD MiddleWare?

I need to retrieve the User's role from the database at this point.

Thank you

Comment: `TracingContext db = new TracingContext()` not work?

Comment: No, because it needs the DbContextOptions as parameter...
public TracingContext(DbContextOptions<TracingContext> options) : base(options)

Comment: so if you pass in the options..., my guess is it would be easier to wrap the TracingContext in another class, which then uses di, to inject the options which is what i believe you setup in the lines above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService` to get the dependency :

```
var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
```